# Node server cannot read headers sent

Tags: node.js, header

I checked Chrome development tool and confirmed that the X-custom headers is being sent. But for some reason, I cannot access X-custom headers on server side. I keep getting 404 error. Any help will be appreciated.

EDITED

```
router.get('/users', function (req, res, next) {
Console.log(req.headers['x-custom'])
if (!req.headers['x-custom']) {
    return res.send(404)
}
```

GET REQUEST

```
svc.getUser = function() {
        return $http.get('/users', {
            headers: {'x-custom' : this.token}
        })
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to print out your header to see what is available? Try console.log(req.headers).

Comment: You are right. I got a 'headers is not defined' error, which means GET request does work except for the headers part.

Comment: Oh, the above was my mistake. The token IS being sent. I omitted req in req.headers. Still cannot read the headers sent.

Comment: what do you get after printing req.headers to console?

Comment: I get this.token, that is, jwt characters.

Comment: Solved the problem. this.token was jwt characters with empty data. I still do not understand why such token incurs the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node lowercases the keys in `req.header`, so you would want to check for the existence of an `x-custom` property rather than `X-custom`:

```
if (!req.headers['x-custom']) {
    return res.send(404)
}
```

Comment: I lowercased req.headers, but it still is not working. Thanks for your suggestion, though.